# separar terminos de un polinomio

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

Tengo un polinomio y quiero separarlo en terminos. o sea, teniendo el polinomio: `"3x^2+x(2-4)-1"` quiero  separarlo en: `3x^2`,`+x(2-4)` y `-1`. Para eso tengo que separarlo por los `+` y `-` que halla exceptuando los que esten adentro de los parentesis.

Intente usar la siguente sentencia: `re.split("[\+|\-][^[\(.*[\+|\-].*\)]]", poly)` para separarlo pero no funciono.

Mi cuestion es: se puede hacer con regex o existe algun modulo de python que pueda hacer esto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podemos crear un funcion para separar los terminos de un polinomio.
La idea es pasar a traves de polinomio y leer todos los caracteres uno por uno (de manera secuencial).
Y lo que el funcion hace esta depende de cual caracter estamos leyendo en el momento.

Necesitamos tres variables claves:

**1. terminoActual** (*un string*)

Cuando pasamos a traves de polinomio, guardamos cada caracter en terminoActual hasta se formada un termino entero y lo guardamos en el variable `terminos`. Y luego, reiniciamos terminoActual para guardar nuevos caracteres y para encontrar otro termino entero.

**2. terminos** (*una lista de string*)

Esta es el resultado de la funcion, guardando todos los terminos en polinomio. El contenido es como asi: `['3x^2','+x(2-4)','-1']`

**3. numeroParentesis** (*un integer*)

Este variable comprobar si estamos dentro de un par de parentesis. Funciona como asi: si se encuentra un `(`, se agrega el valor por 1. Y si se encuentra `)`, se resta el valor por 1. Asi, si numeroParentesis es igual a 0, significa que no estamos dentro de un par de parentesis y viceversa.

Es util cuando encontramos operadores (`+` o `-`). Si estamos fuera de parentesis, cremos un nuevo termino. De otra manera, no creamos un nuevo termino.

---

**El codigo:**

```py
def separarTerminos(polinomio:str) -> []:

    # quitar los space
    polinomio = polinomio.replace(' ','')

    terminoActual = ''
    terminos = []
    numeroParentesis = 0

    # Por cada caracter en polinomio
    for i in range(len(polinomio)):
        caracterActual = polinomio[i]

        # El primero caracter, siempre se agrega a terminoActual
        if i == 0:
            terminoActual = terminoActual + caracterActual

        # El ultimo caracter
        elif i == len(polinomio) - 1:
            terminoActual = terminoActual + caracterActual
            terminos.append(terminoActual)

        # Otros caracteres
        else:

            # Si se encuentra parentesis, actualizamos el valor de numeroParentesis
            if caracterActual == '(':
                numeroParentesis += 1
                terminoActual = terminoActual + caracterActual
            elif caracterActual == ')':
                numeroParentesis -= 1
                terminoActual = terminoActual + caracterActual

            # Si se encuentra operador '+' o '-'
            elif caracterActual == '+' or caracterActual == '-':

                # Si estamos dentro de parentesis
                if numeroParentesis > 0:
                    terminoActual = terminoActual + caracterActual

                # Si estamos fuera de parentesis, crea un nuevo termino
                else:
                    terminos.append(terminoActual)
                    terminoActual = caracterActual

            # Otros caracteres
            else:
                terminoActual = terminoActual + caracterActual

    return terminos
```

Puede probar el funcion con este codigo:

```py
polinomio = '3x^2+x(2-4)-1'

terminos = separarTerminos(polinomio)
for i in terminos:
    print(i)
```

El resultado es:

```
3x^2
+x(2-4)
-1
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la siguiente **expresión regular "([+-]?[^-+]+)"**. Creo la gracia está en su sencillez aunque puede mejorarse.

Se trata de una **expresion regular para obtener cada uno de los terminos del polinomio (secuencia de caracteres) cuyo caracter inicial sea una cadena vacia ('') o bien el caracter '+' o el caracter '-' y cuyo grupo de caracteres final (no incluido) no contenga ni + ni -**. Por ejemplo '3x^2' o '+3x^2' encajarían en tu expresión regular.

[Aquí](https://regex101.com/r/8n3BYD/1) puedes testearla mejor.

Un **ejemplo** con código es el siguiente:

```
import re

#polinomios para el test
p = "3x^2+x(2-4)-1"
p2 = "5x^3-1x^2+6x+33"

#expresion regular para obtener cada uno de los terminos del polinomio cuyo caracter inicial sea "" o bien +,- y cuyo grupo de caracteres final (no incluido) no contenga ni + ni -
rExpr = "([+-]?[^-+]+)"

pAsList = re.split(rExpr, p)
p2AsList = re.split(rExpr, p2)

#Eliminamos de la lista obtenida los strings vacios
print(list(filter(None,pAsList)))
print(list(filter(None,p2AsList)))
```